# RVM source as sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rvm

I'm installing rvm as part of script. After installed I need to run `sudo gem` but to do this I first need to source the script.

The [recommended way](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) is to use `source /home/$USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, but this is not possible with sudo as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/20955/135947).

I [read that](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) source was equivilent to `./$FILE_NAME` but `./home/$USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm` didn't solve my issue.

How can I source rvm so `ruby` and `gem` can be accessed via `sudo`?

*Restarting or logging out is not possible as this is all done in a single shell script.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially tried referencing `rvm` and `gem` by the full path to the file. This got me a step further but led to other issues. From what I've read it seems `sudo` use with `rvm` isn't recommended.

I decided to not use rvm and download the latest ruby from their [official downloads page](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) instead.

**My install_ruby.sh script:** *(run from folder to install in)*

```
# Download ruby
wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.1.tar.gz -P /tmp
# Get SHA256 sum
SHA="$(sha256sum /tmp/ruby-2.4.1.tar.gz | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
# Exit if SHA256 doesn't match expected
[ "$SHA" != "a330e10d5cb5e53b3a0078326c5731888bb55e32c4abfeb27d9e7f8e5d000250" ] && exit;
# Extract and install tar
tar -zxvf /tmp/ruby-2.4.1.tar.gz -C /opt
/opt/ruby-2.4.1/configure
make
sudo make install
```